# Creating reusable HTML view components using Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor helper function that creates a re-usable HTML panel that saves me writing the same HTML over and over again.

```
@helper DefaultPanel(string panelTitle) {
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-logo"><img src="/logo.png"></div>
            <div class=panel-inner">
                <p class="panel-title">@panelTitle</p>
                <div class="panel-content">
                    /* Can I pass content to be rendered in here here? */
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to re-use this helper to fill `.panel-content` with more HTML to allow further flexibility and code reuse - **similar** to something like below:

```
@LayoutHelpers.DefaultPanel("Welcome back") {
    <div class="panel-content-inner">
        <p>Welcome back, please select from the following options</p>
        <a href="#">Profile</a>
        <a href="#">My Defails</a>
    </div>
}
```

Whilst using .NET MVC I've noticed the `Html.BeginForm()` does a similar thing when wrapping the code within the `@using` statement within the `Html.BeginForm` declaration, like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>This content gets rendered within the <form></form> markup.</div>
}
```

But can this done using `@helper` methods? If not, is it possible to create a `HtmlHelper` extension to do a similar thing the way the `Html.BeginForm()` method does?

You can do a very similar thing using the `@section` syntax as seen [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

[image]

This seems like something that would be really useful to be able to do, and odd that there's no easy way to do it on a component level.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve the required functionality.

**1. @helper**

Create @helper which accepts whatever parameters you need plus a function (single object parameter, returns object):

```
@helper DefaultPanel(string panelTitle, Func<object, object> content)
{
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-logo">
                <img src="/logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="panel-inner">
                <p class="panel-title">@panelTitle</p>
                <div class="panel-content">
                    @content(null)
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Usage:

```
@DefaultPanel("title",
@<div class="panel-content-inner">
    <p>Welcome back, please select from the following options</p>
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
    <a href="#">My Defails</a>
</div>
)
```

Your function may also accepts parameters, example [here](http://lostechies.com/hugobonacci/2011/07/11/templates-with-razor/).

**2. HtmlHelper extension method**

Add the following code anywhere in your project:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static HtmlDefaultPanel DefaultPanel(this HtmlHelper html, string title)
        {
            html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(
            "<div class=\"panel\">" +
            "<div class=\"panel-inner\">" +
            "<p class=\"panel-title\">" + title + "</p>" +
            "<div class=\"panel-content\">"
            );

            return new HtmlDefaultPanel(html.ViewContext);
        }
    }

    public class HtmlDefaultPanel : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;
        public HtmlDefaultPanel(ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            _viewContext = viewContext;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _viewContext.Writer.Write(
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@using (Html.DefaultPanel("title2"))
{
    <div class="panel-content-inner">
        <p>Welcome back, please select from the following options</p>
        <a href="#">Profile</a>
        <a href="#">My Defails</a>
    </div>
}
```

The extension method writes directly to the context. The trick is to return a disposable object, which Dispose method will be executed at the end of `using` block.

Comment: Perfect, the second one works like a charm! Thank you for taking the time to write such a thorough answer too.

Comment: For some reason, the second code snippet is giving me an error, the "this" parameter apparently isn't getting passed the html in the curly brackets

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `@helper` methods can do this but `HtmlHelper` extensions certainly can. You've mentioned the `Html.BeginForm()` example which is probably the most well known - all that does is return an object which implements `IDisposable` which means that when the `Dispose()` method is called it just calls the complimentary `Html.EndForm()` method to add the appropriate closing tags.

It would be very simple to do something similar for your HTML code. You can view the source code to the ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelpers at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ - the `BeginForm()` code can be specifically be [viewed here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/FormExtensions.cs).