# ASP.NET Core MVC Reusable HTML Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am starting to dive in deeper to ASP.NET Core and probably my #1 feature with Blazor is the ability to reuse components with `RenderFragment` parameters, such as:

```
<div class="dropdown is-right" id="@this.ClientId">
    <!--trigger button-->
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
        <button class="button" aria-label="@this.AriaLabel" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@($"{this.ClientId}_dropdown")">
            <i class="fas @this.Icon"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!--dropdown-->
    <div class="dropdown-menu is-text-align-right" id="@($"{this.ClientId}_dropdown")" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The C# for this component is basic as well (main property is a `RenderFragment` called `ChildContent` that gets rendered inside the view via `@ChildContent`.

**Is there an equivalent for this with ASP.NET Core MVC apps that don't use Blazor?** I've spent a few hours researching `ViewComponents`, but I can't seem to figure out how my view can access a `RenderFragment` on a `ViewComponent`.

For instance, a small `ViewComponent` I am trying to setup has the following markup:

```
<div class="card card-px-0 shadow-sm">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">@this.Title</h3>
        <div class="card-toolbar">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light">
                Action
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        @ContentTemplate
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

My `ViewComponent` is quite basic as well, as the intention here isn't to have it retrieving data - it's meant to be a basic card template (Bootstrap 5), so if Bootstrap 6 changes the structure of a card (like they did with 4 ==> 5, where it's no longer a "portlet"), I fix it in one spot and the hundreds of views I have will automatically get the new structure, vs. changing it everywhere. Here's the ViewComponent:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Card")]
    public class CardViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the card's body
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ContentTemplate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets card's title
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes this component to render the associated content.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An IViewComponentResult.</returns>
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View("Default");
        }
    }
```

I feel like I'm right on the cusp of figuring this out, but just can't quite get there. I've also reviewed the use of a [`@helper`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518499/creating-reusable-html-view-components-using-razor-in-asp-net-mvc) which is pretty close, but the syntax for a Razor/Blazor app is much cleaner and will let my designer team (who know nothing about .Net) better understand what's happening, e.g.:

```
<Card Title="Section Title">
     <p>I'm the body and would render inside the `ChildContent` RenderFragment!</p>
</Card>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lucky Google search helped me track down [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring) article regarding tag helpers. Utilizing that, I don't need a `RenderFragment` (which seems to be Blazor-specific) - I can add inner HTML as needed, by appending HTML to the `TagHelperOutput` parameter contained inside the `Process` and `ProcessAsync` methods. It's not quite as simple as what `RenderFragment` brings to the table, but it solves my use case.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, You just want to have a Reusable HTML to be a basic card template instead of retrieving data, SO I suggest you to use `Partial View`.

The difference between `Partial View` and `ViewComponent` described in [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0) as:

> Don't use a partial view where complex rendering logic or code
> execution is required to render the markup. Instead of a partial view,
> use a view component.

You can follow the link I shared before to learn more about `Partial View` in Asp.Net core.

Comment: Close! A `Partial View` makes sense, but I need it to allow content inside - all examples I've seen seem to use something akin to `await @RenderPartialView()` (other variants, but general gist) and that doesn't seem to allow child content that I can see. I'm after this type of functionality: https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/, but this won't be a Blazor app - just standard .Net Core.